# PDF Low-Level: Drawing a line in the content object?

Tags: pdf

I have searched extensively online and I have the PDF specification in which I have looked, yet I still can't figure out how to draw a simple black line on a PDF page from the content object's instructions (stream).

Let's say I just want to draw a 1-pixel thickness (assuming 72 dpi) black line at x 400, y 100-300.

This should in theory be a very simple operation, but the PDF spec goes on and on about all kinds of fancy things and appears to forget to explain how I would go about performing this simple operation.

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PDF specification, have a look at chapter 8 (Graphics) and in there section 8.5, Path Construction and Painting.

To draw a simple straight path, you need a "move to" operation followed by a "line to" operation:

```
400 100 m
400 300 l
```

You can then stroke the path using the S operator so your code becomes

```
400 100 m
400 300 l
S
```

By default the color is black so you've already gotten a black line :-) But if you want to make sure you have to set some parameters in the graphics state.

```
0 G
1 w
400 100 m
400 300 l
S
```

The first line now sets the color space to "gray" and puts the shade of grey to 0 (black). The following line sets the line width of your stroked line to 1 user unit (what this comes out as is dependent on your current transformation matrix.

You can apply a neat trick if you really want 1 pixel (please don't for production files though!) and that is to set the width to zero:

```
0 w
```

This gives you "the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide".